# Linux kernel vfs_stat function does not return device id of the file

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to get the device number of a file in kernel mode. The device id I am looking for is something which comes with stat:

Size: 1024         Blocks: 2          IO Block: 1024   directory
Device: **700h/1792d**  Inode: 2           Links: 3
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Context: system_u:object_r:unlabeled_t:s0

I have written code using vfs_stat but do not get the same number

```
struct kstat sb;
int error = 0;
sb.rdev = 0;
error = vfs_fstat(fd, &sb);
if (error) {
    monks_error("Could not get vfs stat %d", error);
}
if (sb.mode == 0060000) {
    monks_info("The device number is %d", MINOR(sb.dev));
}
return  sb.dev;
```

not sure what is wrong here?

Comment: More info please. What error code you got, or what number you got, which is not the same as expected one.

Comment: the error code I am getting is -9. Any clue why this is happening? I am inside kernel

Comment: error code -9 is `-EBADF`. You probably have invalid file descriptor (`fd`).

Comment: Thanks .... I was able to pull out device id from the inode structure, the kdev_t was present in superblock of the file-system. I am able to get minor number from the but somehow major number does not get well. Any suggestions what macros to use here? I am using MINOR & MAJOR file->f_inode->i_sb->s_dev

Comment: Using `MINOR` and `MAJOR` should be ok. May be, returned major number is OK, but your expectations are wrong? In any case concrete example(when major number is incorrect) is required for futher debugging.

Comment: Is this BTRFS ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code sample is insufficient to give a meaningful answer. Also you are inspecting sb.mode even if vfs_fstat failed and what's worse you are unconditionally returning sb.dev.

However, the obvious place to start digging is the stat syscall to see if it does anything to stuff obtained from vfs_fstat. It so happens it does as can be seen in cp_new_stat: tmp.st_dev = encode_dev(stat->dev);

Comment: the error code I am getting is -9. Any clue why this is happening? I am inside kernel